# Setting my PyQt5 app to Portrait Orientation

Tags: python, pyqt5, orientation, raspberry-pi3

So I'm displaying my app on an external raspberry pi display but it is running the app on landscape. I want to display it in a portrait orientation with every subwidget inside to be in a portrait orientation automatically hopefully with only manipulating the QMainWindow.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Saaf")
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 480, 800)  # Adjust the resolution based on your screen size
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)  # Remove window frame
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)  # Keep the window on top
        self.setFixedWidth(480)  # Set the fixed width to enforce portrait orientation
        self.setFixedHeight(800)  # Set the fixed height to enforce portrait orientation
        self.setStyleSheet(
            """
            QMainWindow {
                background-color: #51b09f;
                background-image: url('Images/icons10-recycle-500.png');
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center;
            }
        """
        )

        #set Title Screen
        self.screen1=TitleScreen()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.screen1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.showFullScreen()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Forcing the size alone won't make the device change its orientation. If the screen orientation is landscape, you should change that, not the application.

Comment: Okay. So if I change the orientation to portrait, would I not have to manually set the orientation of all widgets to portrait as well? @musicamante

Comment: That question is irrelevant, because you cannot "set the orientation of all widgets", unless you define a layout that specifically alters geometries based on the orientation (which doesn't seem to be your case). If you're able to set the system orientation, then just consider possible screen aspect ratio and resolutions, which is normally done as long as you're properly using [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) (which is something you should *always* do).

Comment: I am using layouts to set the Qpushbuttons and QLabels in QVBoxLayouts. So what you're telling me is that I just have to change the PyQt app size and aspect ratio to fit the display screen and that is it?

Comment: No. We can assume that you want to show the app at its full extent (probably maximized), meaning that you have to consider layout aspects and system screen capabilities. If you're properly using layout managers and widget size hints/policies, that should happen almost automatically: the whole purpose of layout managers is that they **manage** the layout. If you do something else, it's behavior is up to your experience (and errors). If the UI doesn't resize as expected, it means that you probably did something wrong, but we cannot know it unless you provide a valid [mre].